# Consuming Servicestack SOAP Service

Tags: soap, service, client, servicestack

I'm developing a Servicestack SOAP service. I wanted to generate the proxy class in VS2013 in order to test the consumer, but the proxy is empty :) . Yes, I know that I can use Servicestack's framework in order to develop the client, but my idea is to consume it withount knowing that Servicestack exists. I tried adding [DataContract] to the Requst and Response DTO's and [DataMember] to their properties. The result is the same. I'm interested only for the SOAP service. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the ServiceStack documentation regarding the use of SOAP? Specifically you'll need to look at the following: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#soap-limitations and https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#single-wsdl-namespace

Comment: Yes, I've read those. I have the EntryRequest and then the EntryResponse. I've tried adding [DataContract] and [DataMember] to the request and response. Nothing happens. The only thing I can't set is the namespaces, but as far as I see the WSDL is generated like in the tutorial with the right namespace.

Comment: `EntryRequest` and `EntryResponse` doesn't follow the naming convention required and in the documentation. Have you tried using `Entry` and `EntryResponse` instead? See the second link above.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not following the convention, but I've tried it that way before and it was the same. Will read again those links. Thanks.